# Is there a giant AND symbol/How to solve tons of equations simultaneously

Tags: equation-solving

$$\sum_{k=1}^na_k=a_1+...+a_n$$
$$\prod_{k=1}^na_k=a_1\cdot...\cdot a_n$$
$$\large{?}\small{_{k=1}^na_k=a_1~\&\&...\&\& ~a_n}$$
What in mathematica would allow me to index logical statements in an operation like AND or OR? I'm trying to solve a system of n vector equations, so I can't afford to type them all in manually into the argument of Solve[].

Someone suggested that I take the product of the equations, i.e. if $a_i=(x_i=y_i)$, then 
$$a_1~\&\&...\&\& ~a_n\leftrightarrow \prod_{k=1}^n(x_i-y_i)$$
However, $x_i,y_i$ are vectors, and even their lengths vary, depending on $i$. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: If you apply `And`: `And @@ {a1, a2, a3}` you'll get `a1 && a2 && a3`. `(a1 && a2 && a3)[[2]]` yields `a2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artes solution is probably the easiest

```
And @@ Array[b, 10]
```

but if you like the syntax of `Sum`, you can use it and then transform `Plus` into `And`

```
Sum[b[i], {i, 1, 10}] /. Plus -> And
```

Both of these give the logical `And` of the entries in the array `b`:

```
b[1] && b[2] && b[3] && b[4] && b[5] && b[6] && b[7] && b[8] && b[9] && b[10]
```

Answer (score 2):

`And @@ Outer[f, Range[10]]` gets the job done.

Comment: I feel it would be "easier" to write `And @@ (f /@ Range[10])` here. `Outer` with 2 arguments is `Map`. Or even `And @@ f /@ Range[10]` if you are feeling right associative :P.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom: You are tempting me to post the `TuringMachine` implementation...